# If darkmode button pressed and I refresh the page, the darkmode is forgotten and it resets to light mode

Tags: javascript, local-storage, darkmode

I have watched a number of tutorial videos but I cannot seem to achieve the feature of the webpage remembering that a user selected the dark mode and retaining that even when user refreshes the page. This is for a school project so I was just trying to use local storage. Please can you show me what code needs to be added to mine:

For background info, I have a toggle button that activates a different css stylesheet when the button is clicked that contains the dark mode design (the light mode stylesheet is called stylesheet.css and darkmode stylesheet is called testingstylesheet.css).

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script>
      function toggleTheme() {
          var theme = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0];
          if (theme.getAttribute('href') == 'stylesheet.css') {
              theme.setAttribute('href', 'testingstylesheet.css');
          } else {
              theme.setAttribute('href', 'stylesheet.css');
          }
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<font size=6.5><i style="margin: 5px;position:fixed" onclick="myFunction(this);toggleTheme();toggleImage();" class="fa-solid fa-toggle-off fa-3x;"></i></font>
<script>
      function myFunction(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("fa-toggle-on");
      }
   </script>
</body>
```

I tried many tutorials but nothing is working

Comment: Are you able to recreate this issue in an environment where others can test? Maybe something like Codepen?

Comment: "*I was just trying to use local storage*" - please [edit] your question to include the code of your attempt, we can't explain what the problem is nor help you to solve it otherwise.